# Why in jupyter notebook kernel keeps dying when I try to import keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, shared-libraries

I am using anaconda jupyter notebook on windows. I am using tensorflow 2.1.0, anaconda and keras are up-to-date, but when I try to import numpy it works but when I try to import keras it says kernel died. And it gives an error like:

> Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
>   The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
>   the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
>   Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
>   This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
>   linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
>   You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
>   settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
>   You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
>   variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
>   Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
>   Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
>   SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION

could you help me int this case thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411700/warning-hdf5-library-version-mismatched-error-python-pandas-windows

Comment: Nope, I tried everything here but none helped

Comment: it omits the version difference and gives something like this "  h5py is running against HDF5 1.10.5 when it was built against 1.10.4, this may cause problems
  '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
Using TensorFlow backend."

Comment: solved the program

Comment: did you use PIP to install Tensorflow 2? I recommend you uninstall it then reinstall it using CONDA, I had similar problems when I installed Tensorflow 2 with pip.

Comment: no manually downloaded