# error with hdf5 and tensorflow and python 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

when i import tflearn or tensorflow i have this big error i have alwready tried to install and uninstall HDF5 by doing conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.8.15 and all the instruction on this stack overflow webpage [Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error*** python pandas windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411700/warning-hdf5-library-version-mismatched-error-python-pandas-windows) my python is 3.7 and the IDE is syder

***this is the error***

```
{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but

linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
                  Configured on: 2019-03-04
                  Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
                    Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
              Uname information: Windows
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode:
              Debugging Symbols:
                        Asserts:
                      Profiling:
             Optimization Level:

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries:
  Statically Linked Executables: OFF
                        LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
                     H5_LDFLAGS:
                     AM_LDFLAGS:
                Extra libraries:
                       Archiver:
                         Ranlib:

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                       CPPFLAGS:
                    H5_CPPFLAGS:
                    AM_CPPFLAGS:
                         CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                      H5_CFLAGS:
                      AM_CFLAGS:
               Shared C Library: YES
               Static C Library: YES

                        Fortran: OFF
               Fortran Compiler:
                  Fortran Flags:
               H5 Fortran Flags:
               AM Fortran Flags:
         Shared Fortran Library: YES
         Static Fortran Library: YES

                            C++: ON
                   C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                      C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
                   H5 C++ Flags:
                   AM C++ Flags:
             Shared C++ Library: YES
             Static C++ Library: YES

                            JAVA: OFF
                   JAVA Compiler:

Features:
---------
                   Parallel HDF5: OFF
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes:
              Large Parallel I/O:
              High-level library: ON
                    Threadsafety: OFF
             Default API mapping: v110
  With deprecated public symbols: ON
          I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
                             MPE:
                      Direct VFD:
                         dmalloc:


     Packages w/ extra debug output:


    API Tracing: OFF
            Using memory checker: OFF
 Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
          Function Stack Tracing: OFF
       Strict File Format Checks: OFF
    Optimization Instrumentation:
Bye...
```

thanks for helping and i like this error that says bye :-) even if it's 
annoying

Comment: Is your issue resolved now ? Else, Please can you try `pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force`

Comment: Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above so that we can mention it as an answer for the benefit of the community.Thanks !

Comment: yes it works i just have an error module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession' but this is something else and i will found out what is the problem, thanks it works now

Comment: Glad, it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

`HDF5 library version mismatched error` was resolved with the below code

```
pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force
```

Comment: @super learner, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You