# RuntimeError: HDF5 library version mismatch. 1.14.x != 1.12.2

Tags: python, anaconda, runtime-error, spyder, hdf5

I'm attempting to use a program called Brainrender, through spyder within the anaconda prompt.
I have created an environment using the following in the anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n brainrender24 spyder numpy=1.23 python=3.8 scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython
```

I then updated conda, activated the environment, updated spyder, and installed Brainrender version 2.1 using pip.

When opening spyder, and running one of the test-programs provided by the developers, I encountered this error:

```
RuntimeError: HDF5 library version mismatch. 1.14.x != 1.12.2
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411700/warning-hdf5-library-version-mismatched-error-python-pandas-windows), and I tried the following suggestions from there, without any luck.

I'm working in Windows 11. All the following was done within the environment:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling hdf5 using pip - resulted in the same error.

  ```
  pip uninstall h5py
  pip install h5py
  ```
- Uninstalling and reinstalling hdf5 using conda - resulted in the same error.

  ```
  conda uninstall h5py
  conda install h5py
  ```
- Uninstalling, and reinstalling an earlier version of hdf5=3.9.0, using both pip and conda:

  ```
  pip install h5py==3.9.0
  conda install h5py==3.9.0
  ```
- Using the following command both in conda and pip, after uninstalling hdf5:

  ```
  conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.12.2
  ```
- Using the following command both in conda and pip, after uninstalling hdf5:

  ```
  conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.14
  ```

The complete output from the console in spyder is the following:

```
Python 3.8.18 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 10 2023, 15:37:54) \[MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)\]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 8.12.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('D:/Data/Sol/Lightsheet_images/brainrender-master/brainrender-master/examples/Add-Cells-test.py', wdir='D:/Data/Sol/Lightsheet_images/brainrender-master/brainrender-master/examples')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File d:\data\sol\lightsheet_images\brainrender-master\brainrender-master\examples\add-cells-test.py:15
from brainrender import Scene

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\brainrender\__init__.py:15
from brainrender.scene import Scene

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\brainrender\\scene.py:22
from brainrender.actors import Volume

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\brainrender\actors\__init__.py:3
from brainrender.actors.neurons import Neuron, make_neurons

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\brainrender\actors\neurons.py:4
from morphapi.morphology.morphology import Neuron as MorphoNeuron

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\morphapi\morphology\morphology.py:5
import neurom as nm

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\neurom\__init__.py:58
from neurom.core.dataformat import COLS

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\neurom\core\__init__.py:32
from neurom.core.soma import Soma

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\neurom\core\soma.py:34
from morphio import SomaError, SomaType

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\brainrender24\lib\site-packages\morphio\__init__.py:10
raise RuntimeError(f'HDF5 library version mismatch. 1.14.x != {\_h5py.version.hdf5_version}')

RuntimeError: HDF5 library version mismatch. 1.14.x != 1.12.2
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're specifying the conda-forge channel and Python 3.8? Looking at the [documentation I could find](https://brainglobe.info/documentation/setting-up/conda.html#installation) it looks like you should be able to do `conda create -n brainrender24 python=3.10 pip spyder`, activate the new env, then `pip install brainrender` and let pip figure out the remaining dependencies - what happens if you try that? As a rule I would delete an env and recreate it rather than try and uninstall/reinstall packages which could aggravate version conflicts.